# DDR4 RAM not running in dual channel?

Tags: memory, motherboard, dual-channel

I recently upgraded my PC and swapped out my CPU/mobo/RAM in the process.
Now I have a

- Ryzen 3 1300x processor,
- MSI B350M GAMING PRO motherboard and
- 2x8GB G.SKILL Ripjaws V 2400Mhz RAM,

running on a Windows 10 Pro machine.

For some reason, even though I have both sticks installed and recognized in the system (I have 16GB of available RAM), it is marking them as Single Channel in CPU-Z. I don't see any settings in the BIOS to enable "Dual-Channel" mode for my RAM so I'm not sure how to fix this.

As far as I know, Single-Channel vs Dual-Channel RAM has a big impact on Ryzen performance, because of the architecture behind the Infinity Fabric, so I am looking to fix this ASAP.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is [here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633289/how-can-i-ask-windows-about-if-the-ram-is-running-in-single-dual-or-quad-channe).

The WMI command

```
wmic memorychip get InterleavePosition
```

will tell you what the memory channel situation is.

You can check the motherboard manual to see which RAM slots are related.  Perhaps 1 and 2 should be populated first, perhaps 1 and 3.  It varies by manufacturer.

Comment: There are only 2 available slots on the motherboard.

Comment: Reading the [Manual of your Motherboard](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B350M-GAMING-PRO#down-manual) you only have two(!) DIMM slots: _DIMMA1_ and _DIMMB1_. Unfortunately, I do not know why only one of them is recognized.

Comment: @zx485 Both are recognized, the author indicates it’s just running in single channel mode, hence the author’s question

Answer (score -1):

http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/M7A39v1.4.zip contains your manual, and a review of it showed no option to enable or disable Dual Channel memory. Therefore, if here's no way to turn it on/off, the memory modules are the likely cause. If they are not identical, you won't get Dual Channel mode, so check both of them, and replace one with a module identical to the module in the PC.